# How can I make the mouse wheel button perform a double-click in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, mouse-wheel, double-click

I have a "generic" mouse, and like most mice these days, the wheel has a click action as well. My "Microsoft IntelliMouse 1.1A PS/2 Compatible" Mouse used to have software that would allow the wheel click to perform a double-click.

Does Windows 7 allow this, and or is there software I can get that would enable this? The MS IntelliMouse drivers don't work - the wheel click must be recognised some other way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) could do this.

```
MButton::Send {LButton 2}
```

Comment: I had never heard of this great utility. THANK YOU! This is going to be useful in so many other ways.

Comment: @Bern; I know, it's brilliant, I love it.

Answer (score 3):

[Double Click](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Double-Click.shtml) works on my bluetooth mouse and Windows 7 x64.

> The Double Click application was designed to be a small program that will turn your middle mouse button into a double click function. It's much smaller than other 3rd party mouse enhancers, as it only does one thing. This will definitely save you getting RSI.