# Renaming files by middle clicking?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, mouse, macros

Is there any way to set up windows explorer so that I can rename files by clicking on them with the middle mouse button? I'm tired of having to slow double click or use the right click menu.

(Please feel free to write if and why you think this is a bad idea, as idk what else is bound to middle click in file explorer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the middle mouse button behave as a double-click in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/442165/make-the-middle-mouse-button-behave-as-a-double-click-in-windows-7)

Comment: Frame challenge:- What's wrong with using F2? Do you want to do this without touching the keyboard? [This would feel an odd choice, as you're about to use it to do the rename;) Alternatively, speed up your double-click recognition so you don't have to wait so long before the second click.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thx for your comment, I didn't know F2 could be used to rename files.

Comment: Yeah, since Noah was wondering if it might rain ;)) It's one of those legacy commands people forget ever existed, like alt/F4 to close.